# Download Gmail Messages One by One

Tags: .net, gmail, imap

I need a .net IMAP Library that downloads the messages in a gmail folder one by one not all at once.

That's because when I connect to the gmail account and try to download the messages in a folder, the application hangs until all the messages in that folder are downloaded into the memory so that if the connection disconnected, the whole process fails.

Comment: Can you not get the headers, then get each message detail by the header ID using your library?

Comment: @cjk Getting headers is not that fast - each email contains many lines of them. **ENVELOPE** and **BODYSTRUCTURE** commands are better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any decent IMAP client allows you download 1 message at time.
Normally you should only get only 1 message at time, otherwise if thousands of messages, you run out of memory.

It depens on application, if you run UI apllication, you should run IMAP on different thread, to keep UI not freezing.

Answer (score 0):

To improve user expreience, you may want to download only basic message info (subject, from, to, attachment count) first to fill the list.

**ENVELOPE** and **BODYSTRUCTURE** are the IMAP commands for that.

You can try [Mail.dll IMAP component](http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail/) for that:
http://www.lesnikowski.com/blog/index.php/get-email-information-from-imap-fast/

Please note the Mail.dll is a commercial product I created.